# How can I display a popup window to a user after being on my PHP site for 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, php

Assuming they will be moving around different pages. How can I achieve this (timing doesn't need to be precise).

can I achieve it with a cookie with a time value set? Also I would like the option of "remind me later" (wait another 10 minutes) and "don't show this again".

Comment: This is very possible but will require to you plan it out, just like anything/everything else.... Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have achieved it, seems to work well enough, code needs some tidying up however its all there (have used small timer values for testing). I have decided to just use a page redirect to a splash page since most browsers will block the popup. this code needs to be on every page - in my case since I use templates I just added it to my header.

```
<?php


if (!isset($_COOKIE['rating_time']) || !isset($_COOKIE['rating_show'])) {
//cookies are not set, so set them
setcookie("rating_time", strtotime("+10 seconds"), time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");
setcookie("rating_show", "True", time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");

} 



if (($_COOKIE["rating_show"] == True)) {
  //cookie is set and user has not requested to ignore the message yet

    $cookie_time = $_COOKIE["rating_time"];

if (strtotime("now") > $_COOKIE["rating_time"])
{
    echo "time has lapsed";
    //Insert JS here to display popup or redirect to splash page

    //update the cookie or else popup will keep showing
    setcookie("rating_show", "False", time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");

}   else { echo "time has not lapsed"; }

} 


//if they click remind me later

$newtime = strtotime("+13 seconds");
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookieLater() {
var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (3650 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = "rating_time=" + <?php echo $newtime; ?> + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}


</script>

<a href="javascript:setCookieLater()">Remind me later</a>


<?php

//if they click don't show again
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setCookieIgnore() {
var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (3650 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = "rating_show=False;" + expires + ";path=/";
}


</script>

<a href="javascript:setCookieIgnore()">Don't show this again</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set something to happen at some point in the future.

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    alert('foo');
}, 1000*60*10);
```

Take and modify this to fit your needs.

Comment: **Issue 1** *"Assuming they will be moving around different pages"* the second that client moves pages the time is reset. I know OP clearly states *"(timing doesn't need to be precise)"* but if a client is on one page for 9 minutes and moves to another it will then take a further 10 minutes before receiving the alert, 19 minutes is way off.

Comment: Yep, good point. I didn't see that requirement - so this answer doesn't fit the needs, FYI.